# Синхронизация баз данных

Tags: mysql

Подскажите будет ли правильно использовать Master-Slave для синхронизации двух баз данных в таком кейсе:
Имеется объект, доступ к интернету появляется раз в сутки, все сутки приложение на этом объекте пишет данные в базу данных, а потом Master база делает pull со слейва. Подобных объектов может быть неограниченное количество.

Возможно подскажите как правильно реализовать?

Comment: `Master база делает pull со слейва` наоборот слейв делает пулл с мастера. Иначе это уже Master-Master репликация - что крайне чревато и нестабильно. А если ещё и таких объектов много - ИМХО просто репликацией такую задачу не решить, нужно писать вручную алгоритмы синхронизации.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, если быть точнее, мне нужно переключаться на локальную базу данных в случае если отвалится удаленная

Comment: а что если в локальной и удалённой базе образовались конфликтующие записи с одним ключом? А что если этот ключ ещё и записан уже в другие таблицы? Этот процесс, о котором вы написали - называется синхронизация, и пишется для любого ПО отдельно - так как процесс очень тонкий, и должен учитывать особенности ПО. Но может быть ошибаюсь, и есть решения для синхронизации БД любой сложности ( если в БД корректно указаны FOREIGN KEY  - теоретически возможно что-то более менее универсальное). Только это далеко уже не репликация.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, спасибо за ответ, буду копать дальше